# Deploying Code to Heroku (Issues?)

Tags: python, git, heroku, github

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python

When i'm trying to deploy my code through `$ git push heroku master` i get an error:

```
    Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.132' to the list      of known hosts.
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Next, I was able to add the RSA host key for that IP address by `$ heroku keys:add` but I still get this error:

```
   Found existing public key: /Users/opalkale/.ssh/github_rsa.pub
   Uploading SSH public key /Users/opalkale/.ssh/github_rsa.pub... done
   (venv)Opal-Kales-MacBook-Pro:helloflask opalkale$ git push heroku master
   Permission denied (publickey).
```

What am I doing wrong...?

Comment: Mark the correct answer please :)

Comment: @Learath How do I do this if I don't have enough reputation points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your id_rsa.pub SSH key to your Heroku account online: https://dashboard.heroku.com/account

And make sure that the corresponding private key has been added to your identity

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

E.g.

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```

Comment: Make sure it is the right public key. It is okay to have more than one public key.

Comment: Nice. Was my answer the solution?